# Time ordering of integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, definition, notation

Is $$T\int\mathrm{d}^4x\phi^4(x)$$ just notation for $$\int\mathrm{d}^4x~T\phi^4(x)$$ since after integrating we have no time dependence anymore?

Comment: @Steeven $T$ is the time ordering operator...

Comment: The time ordering symbol is only relevant if you have a product of fields sitting at space-time points at different times (e.g. $\phi(x) \phi(y)$ with $x^0 \ne y^0$. So I do not see why in your case (with $\phi(x)^4$) time ordering should be an issue. The definition of a product of field operators at the same space-time point has other problems, but this is a different story...

Comment: @Hyperon I know that it is problematic that our fields are distribution valued but in the Lagrange density of $\phi^4$-theory we have also $\phi^4(x)$. How can be that it there is well-defined?

Comment: It depends what you want to do. If you compute the perturbative expansion of an n-point function $\langle 0| T\phi(x_1) \ldots \phi(x_n) |0 \rangle$ in the $\phi^4$ model, the $\phi^4$ term in the interaction Lagrangian will not cause problems (you find the relevant procedure in all QFT textbooks). However, if you are interested in correlation functions of a composite operators like $\langle 0 | T \phi^2(x_1) \phi^2(x_2) | 0 \rangle$, you need additional renormalization constants already in the free theory that cannot be absorbed in the mass term or the field renormalization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the time-ordering symbol is always meant to be applied on operators before the integral, but only on operators located at different points, so it doesn't quite apply to the case you've shown. For instance, we can write
$$
T \int d^4 x d^4 y \phi_1(x)\phi_2(y) = \int d^4 x d^4 y T \{ \phi_1(x) \phi_2(y) \}. 
$$
The example you have shown never appears in QFT. What appears instead is
$$
T \exp \int d^4 x :\phi^4:(x)
$$
This is interpreted by doing the Taylor expansion for the operator and then applying the time-ordering symbol so this is equal to
\begin{align}
& T \left\{ 1 + \int d^4 x :\phi^4:(x) + \frac{1}{2!} \int d^4 x :\phi^4:(x) \int d^4 y :\phi^4(): + \cdots \right\}\\
&\qquad = 1 + \int d^4 x :\phi^4:(x) + \frac{1}{2!} \int d^4 x \int d^4 y T \left\{ :\phi^4:(x)  :\phi^4:(y) \right\} + \cdots 
\end{align}
Note that the normal-ordering symbol means that we should treat $:\phi^4:(x)$ as a single operator, not as a product of four operators.

Comment: Thank you! So does that mean when we expand the S-matrix we time-order only at order 2 and higher because our fields are distribution valued operators for which the product isn’t well defined?

Comment: yes to both points, but they are not inherently related. Taking products of local operators is quite a tricky matter and is a separate issue.